# Horizontal slide pages needs to set position top when click on the next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I have created horizontal scrolling pages using **Owl Carousel**. It contains page next & previous buttons at the bottom.

**What I need is:**

When we click on the button, the **top of the page should be visible**. Now it shows the bottom part of the next/prev page.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: false,
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        center: true,
        mouseDrag: false,
        touchDrag: false,
        autoHeight: true,
        margin: 10,
        smartSpeed: 500,
        URLhashListener: true,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        startPosition: 'URLHash'
    });
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.page {
    height: 10rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 1500px;
}
.one {
  background: #bec4bd;
}
.two {
  background: green;
}
.three {
  background: #41253c;
}
.linkA {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.linkB {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="page one" data-hash="page1">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page2" class="linkB">Page 2</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="page two" data-hash="page2">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page1" class="linkA">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="linkB">Page 3</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="page three" data-hash="page3">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page2" class="linkA">Page 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/taf9cr1s/)

Have a great day..!

StaySafe@Home

Comment: For scroll to top transition: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `translated.owl.carousel` event to call your function when the page changed:

```
owl.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
})
```

Check the following example:

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    loop: false,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    center: true,
    mouseDrag: false,
    touchDrag: false,
    autoHeight: true,
    margin: 10,
    smartSpeed: 500,
    URLhashListener: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    startPosition: 'URLHash'
});
owl.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.page {
    height: 10rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 1500px;
}
.one {
  background: #bec4bd;
}
.two {
  background: green;
}
.three {
  background: #41253c;
}
.linkA {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.linkB {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="page one" data-hash="page1">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page2" class="linkB">Page 2</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="page two" data-hash="page2">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page1" class="linkA">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="linkB">Page 3</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="page three" data-hash="page3">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page2" class="linkA">Page 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great..! Is it possible to add a transition for scroll to top function?

Comment: Transition on the scroll is completely different question, but you can probably find multiple solutions/examples for this in stackoverflow :) shouldn't be too hard now that you know how/what/where to implement this.

Comment: No problem, let me try.. Have a great day..!